# Drawing a political spectrum

Tags: technical-drawing

What would be the best way of drawing a political spectrum diagram like this one:

[image: example]

Comment: Definitely `TikZ`, check http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/ for a suitable starting point.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}

\fbox{\begin{picture}(200,200)
\thicklines
\put(100,10){\line(0,1){180}}
\put(10,100){\line(1,0){180}}
\put(100,190){\makebox(0,0)[b]{\textsc{TiKZ}}}
\put(100,10){\makebox(0,0)[t]{\textsc{PsTricks}}}
\put(10,100){\makebox(0,0)[r]{\rotatebox{90}{\textsc{Picture Mode}}}}
\put(190,100){\makebox(0,0)[l]{\rotatebox{-90}{\textsc{MetaPost}}}}
\put(50,150){\makebox(0,0){Easy}}
\put(150,150){\makebox(0,0){Hard}}
\put(50,50){\makebox(0,0){Clear}}
\put(150,50){\makebox(0,0){Obscure}}

\end{picture}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I should add that apart from giving a bias towards picture mode, the placement of the other packages is arbitrary:-)

Comment: Shouldn't the adjectives be on the lines and the packages be in the boxes?

Comment: How is it possible to automatically scale this image to the page?

Comment: @asmeurer you'd better vote for Jake's version:-)

Comment: `\setlength\unitlength{\dimexpr\textwidth/200}` or a bit less than that if you still have an fbox aroun dit, also you'd need \noindent orput it in a center env. If you want the fonts to scale as well don;t do that instead use \resizebox just to scale the whole thing to be textwidth wide

Answer (score 11):

I would (of course) use PGFPlots for this. Once the axis is set up, you can add your data in a really easy and clear way:

```
Difficulty Clarity Package
0.8        0.6     PSTricks
0.6        0.8     TikZ
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-1, xmax=1,
    ymin=-1, ymax=1,
    axis equal image,
    xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
    axis lines*=middle,
    after end axis/.code={
        \node at (current axis.right of origin) [anchor=west] {Easy};
        \node at (current axis.left of origin) [anchor=east] {Hard};
        \node at (current axis.above origin) [anchor=south] {Clear};
        \node at (current axis.below origin) [anchor=north] {Obscure};
    }
]

\addplot [
    nodes near coords, 
    mark=*, 
    only marks, 
    point meta=explicit symbolic
] table [meta=Package] {
    Difficulty Clarity Package
    0.8 0.6 PSTricks
    0.6 0.8 TikZ
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I suppose I'd better give you +1 :-)

Answer (score 8):

This is quite straightforward with »[tikZ/PGF](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)«.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,6)  node[above]                 {Freedom}  -- (0,-6) node[below]                 {Authority}
          (-6,0) node[xshift=-6pt,rotate=90] {Equality} -- (6,0)  node[xshift=6pt,rotate=-90] {Inequality};
    \node at (-3,3) {Social Democracy};
    \node at (3,3) {Classical Liberalism};
    \node at (-3,-3) {Communism};
    \node at (3,-3) {Facism};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 5):

An option using the `positioning` library from [`tikz`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz)

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5cm]
  \node(origin) at (0,0){};
  % nodes on horizontal and vertical
  \node(freedom)[above=of origin]{FREEDOM};
  \node(authority)[below=of origin]{AUTHORITY};
  \node(equality)[left=of origin]{\rotatebox{90}{EQUALITY}};
  \node(inequality)[right=of origin]{\rotatebox{-90}{INEQUALITY}};
  % nodes on diagonals
  \node(socdemo)[above left=3cm of origin]{Social democracy};
  \node(classlib)[above right=3cm of origin]{Classical liberalism};
  \node(facism)[below right=3cm of origin]{Facism};
  \node(facism)[below left=3cm of origin]{Communism};
  % connect horizontal and vertical nodes
  \draw(equality)--(inequality);
  \draw(freedom)--(authority);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

A version in [Metapost](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107489/what-is-metapost-metafont-and-how-can-i-get-started-using-it), to show a couple of useful features.

[image]

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";
beginfig(1);
path xx, yy; 
xx = (left--right) scaled 5cm; 
yy = xx rotated 90;

draw xx;
draw yy;

defaultfont := "qx-qtmr-sc";
label.bot("Authority", point 0 of yy);
label.top("Freedom",   point 1 of yy);
label.lft("Equality"   infont defaultfont rotated +90, point 0 of xx);
label.rt ("Inequality" infont defaultfont rotated -90, point 1 of xx);

defaultfont := "qx-qtmr";
label("Classical Liberalism", 1/2[point 1 of xx, point 1 of yy]);
label("Social Democracy",     1/2[point 0 of xx, point 1 of yy]);
label("Communism",            1/2[point 0 of xx, point 0 of yy]);
label("Facism",               1/2[point 1 of xx, point 0 of yy]);

setbounds currentpicture to bbox currentpicture scaled 1.05;

endfig;
end.
```

### Notes

- There's only one number --- `5cm` to scale the *x*-axis.  Everything else is positioned relative to this.  This means you can rescale the whole figure with minimal effort when required.
- For a path `p` with a single segment `point 0 of p` is the beginning, and `point 1 of p` is the other end.
- If `a` and `b` are points (defined as `pair`) then `1/2[a,b]` is the point half way between them.
- It's helpful to be familiar with the contents of your local `psfonts.map` file, in order to choose the right fonts in the right encodings for Metapost.  Here I've picked out TeX Gyre Termes in regular and regular-small-caps style, and in the `qx` encoding.

  In plain Metapost strings like this you are limited to ASCII characters, so the only thing that matters about the choice of encoding is that the characters from `0x20` to `0x7e` are mapped as you expect.  If you want accents and or maths in your labels, then you need to call TeX with the `btex` and `etex` mechanism.  For full flexibility and to automatically use your document fonts investigate the [`gmp`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/gmp) package, or [`luamplib`](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/luatex/generic/luamplib).
- If you keep your diagram centered on the origin, then the `setbounds` trick at the end adds a margin all round your drawing.

Comment: Complementary note: For the LaTeX users who do not want to use LuaLaTeX and thus `luamplib`, I think that the most powerful and flexible solution for labels management is the `latexmp` package (which can be used with `gmp`). This at the cost of a double compilation, which can be automatized anyway: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmp